# Search for pattern in part of the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to search for a pattern in a string field which contains an email and an additional comment. An example is the following:

```
Dear XXX: We are sorry to inform you that your 
application has been put on hold because YYY. 

Additional comments: this application was not held for ZZZ.
```

The pattern I am looking for is "ZZZ" in the email body. But not in the comments. If I just do `field like 'ZZZ'`, I will be picking up this record, which is not what I want. Is there a way to carry out the search accurately in this case?

Note that a subset of the records have the field structured this way, others may not contain this structure (i.e. no `Additional comments:`. The bold letters mark the structure of the subset.

Comment: please provide an example where a record would return.

Comment: If there will always be "Additional comments:", you could do something like... `where field like '%ZZZ%' and not field like 'Additional comments:%ZZZ%'`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I think this is the way to do it. If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If the only indicator of additional comments that is reliable is that the text is bold, you are then at the mercy of how you store it.  Is your text in HTML or RTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will always be "Additional comments:", you could do something like...

```
WHERE field LIKE '%ZZZ%' AND field NOT LIKE 'Additional comments:%ZZZ%'
```

Comment: From the post: Note that a subset of the records have the field structured this way, others may not contain this structure (i.e. no **Additional comments:**. The bold letters mark the structure of the subset.

Comment: @dfundako That would not be a problem since the condition `not field like 'Additional comments:%ZZZ%'` would just be ignored, which fits my purpose.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591: there is a catch to your solution. Some records may have the search pattern in both the email body and the additional comments. Those records will be excluded by your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
WITH cte
AS
    (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Additional Comment',[field]) = 0 THEN [field]
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Additional Comment',[field]) > 0 THEN 
                LEFT([field],CHARINDEX('Additional Comment',[field])-1)
        END AS Adjusted_field
    FROM table)

SELECT Adjusted_field
FROM cte
WHERE
    Adjusted_field LIKE '%zzz%'
```

This uses a CTE to basically remove anything after the "Additional Comment" line in the text field.  The CASE statement uses CHARINDEX to search for the "Additional Comment" if that string is not found (CHARINDEX =0) then it returns the whole text field, if the string is found then it only returns the text that came before (LEFT) of the "additional comment" string.

Then in the final SELECT query you can search for the desired string in the adjusted text field which now entirely ignores anything that came after the "additional comment" string.